# Strange characters after typing an AT command in serial monitor

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, softwareserial

I'm trying to test AT commands (I am working with an  Arduino Uno and a GSM/GPRS SIM900  shield; my system is ubuntu 14.10) . Yesterday when I was testing , all  ran well.. For example after typing AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","ooredoo" in the serial monitor it  showed me OK.. but But now it  shows me strange  characters.

This is my code

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    SoftwareSerial GPRS(2,3);


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 GPRS.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.write("start");



}

void loop() {

  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
     while(GPRS.available()) 
     Serial.write(GPRS.read()); 

  while(Serial.available())
    GPRS.write(Serial.read());  


}
```

And this it is the result of AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","ooredoo" typed in the serial monitor

[image]

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Did you select the right baud rate? I get these strange characters when I have set it wrong.

Comment: i didn't change anything...it worked like this yesterday,but now i have this strange characters...what can be the problem?

Comment: You haven't changed any settings, but have you knocked a wire.  It could be a loose connection or a bad ground connection.

Comment: bad connection? i don't know..but the shield work normaly..the red led is on, the station led is also on and the net led blind every 3 seconds

Answer (score 1):

for those who have this issue, i resolve this by changing the speed baud of my GPRS Shield :

```
GPRS.begin(2400); 
Serial.begin(9600);
```

and if you want to test AT command directly on the serial monitor you must use 2400 anywhere

```
GPRS.begin(2400); 
    Serial.begin(2400);
```

and don't forget to change also  the speed on the serial monitor to 2400
I hope this will help someone